# How can I create a custom action menu list

Tags: android

I need to create a custom list for displaying action menu items. At the moment i am inflating the menu.

How can I create an adapter and a custom row for actionbar menu? Can I use the menuInflator or do I have to use something else?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. From what you wrote it seems that you want a ListView in the ActionBar. Do you want to have a ListView in your main layout that has the same elements as the actionbar items?

Comment: @VM I need to create a menu list. right now the getSupportMenuInflater, does all the work. i need to create my own list

Comment: Well you can specify your menu items in the R.menu.menu_once file. It has a list of items that will appear in the menu. Or are you saying you want to add menu items dynamically for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your menu items in the R.menu.menu_one file by adding items to it, from the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" />
</menu>
```

This will add two items to the ActionBar.

You can also add items to the ActionBar dynamically like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322848/how-can-i-add-an-action-bar-item-during-run-time):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Item1").setIcon(R.drawable.myicon)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Item2").setIcon(R.drawable.othericon)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return true;
}
```